# NuGet on VSTS strategy

Tags: nuget

I have the following scenario:

- We want to create nuget packages on VSTS
- We want the packages to be available for an external party *(preferably no login, tokens...?)*
- For our developers we want to have the symbols for that package coming from VSTS
- The Debug packages should have the output + pdb files. (no source)

If I understand correctly, we can package using `-Symbols`.
This creates 2 packages, 1 with Release build and 1 with Debug build + symbols and source. How am I supposed to distribute this to achieve the above requirements?

*Note: the packages are considered private so we can't simply upload to nuget.org.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to another site (seems more appropriate for SO or maybe even SuperUser). In any case, it's not really clear and does not seem to fit SE.SE.

Answer (score 2):

VSTS can [create Nuget Feeds](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/feeds/create-feed). You can host your own feed and publish your packages there. You may want to have two feeds, one for release packages and one for your internal debugging needs.

You can set permissions on the feeds, so that should be no problem. You can obviously make them available to just anybody (no login) but that is contradictory to your requirement of "not public".

Comment: Thx, how would you go about packing the Debug packages? Using -Symbols (that includes the source code which is unwanted) or manually using a nuspec file? I want to use the VSTS as symbols server..?

Comment: Actually I have 2 feeds but the development feed should not have the symbols package right? Just the Debug build package? I'm a bit confused about the symbols package vs Debug package publishing.